# access object from boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

in my program I start a loop function using `boost::thread`:

the code is like this:

```
void MyClass::StartSim()
{
    _thread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::BoostTick, boost::ref(*this)));
}

void MyClass::BoostTick()
{
    while (!_shutdown)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and works fine...
now I have a funcion like this:

```
Ray MyClass:GetRay()
{
    // here I use an object that is used inside the while loop
}
```

but I got exception...

is there a way to avoid the exception?

thanks in advance

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I have this exception : `Unhandled exception at 0x0000000000000000 in MyClass.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.`

Comment: Rough guess? You're calling GetRay() through a null MyClass pointer.

Comment: the strange thing is that the exception happens after some right calls... seems a thread issue